# How to implement a profile?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a token based authorization. Authorization happens well there are no errors. But now need to somehow display the data of an authorized user. Please tell me how to properly implement the profile on the client (Angular 6)? 
I have this server:

controller:

```
const db = require('../config/db.config.js')
const User = db.user
const errorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler')

module.exports.getProfile = async function(req, res) {
    try {
       await User.findOne({ id: req.user.id}, (user) => {
           res.json({
               success: true,
               user: user,
               message: "Successful"
           }) 
        })
    }catch(e) {
        errorHandler(req, e)
    }
}
```

routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const controller = require('../controllers/user')
const passport = require('passport')

router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), controller.getProfile)

module.exports = router
```

passport:

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt
const db = require('../config/db.config.js')
const User = db.user


const options = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), 
    secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY
}

module.exports = passport => {
    passport.use(
        new JwtStrategy(options, async (payload, done) => {
            try {
                const user = await User.findById(payload.userId).toJSON('username id')

                if (user) {
                    done(null, user)
                } else {
                    done(null, false)
                }
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        })
    )
}
```

And here is a part of the client:

app-components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './shared/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const potentialToken = localStorage.getItem('auth-token')
    if (potentialToken !== null) {
      this.auth.setToken(potentialToken)
    }
  }
}
```

auth.service:

```
import { Injectable, Optional } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { User } from "../interfaces";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

    private token = null;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        @Optional() private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        @Optional() private _router: Router
    ) {}

    login(user: User): Observable<{token: string}> {  
        return this.http.post<{token: string}>('/api/auth/login', user)
            .pipe(
                tap(
                    ({token}) => {
                        localStorage.setItem('auth-token', token)   
                        this.setToken(token)                     
                    }
                )
            )
    }

    setToken(token: string) {
        this.token = token
    }

    getToken(): string {
        return this.token
    }


    isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        return !!this.token
    }

    logout() {
        this.setToken(null) 
        localStorage.clear()

    }

}
```

token.interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router){
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            req = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: this.auth.getToken()
                }
            })
        }
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleAuthError(error)
            )
        )
    }

    private handleAuthError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
        if (error.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/sign_in']), {
                queryParams: {
                    sessionFailed: true
                }
            }
        }

        return throwError(error)
    }

}
```

What need to implement on the client to display user data. Tell me please, I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

> You just need to create a Service class called `UserService` which will keep the information related to logged in user.
>
> Whenever login action is performed successfully, just get the user details and fill it in `UserService` class.

### user.service.ts

```
export class UserService {

  private currentUser$: new BehaviorSubject<User>; //<-- check your user type 

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getCurrentUser() {
     this.currentUser$;
  }

  setCurrentUser(user:User){
    this.currentUser$.next(user); //update the current user
  }

}
```

This  service class will give the Observable and you can use it any component or service class.

Comment: Something does not work, no data is displayed `private currentUser$ = new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as User);` html: `<strong>{{auth.currentUser$.username}}</strong>`

Comment: use `<strong>{{ (auth.currentUser$ | async)?. username }}</strong>`

Comment: In general, nothing is displayed, even there are no errors

Comment: Did you set the `currentUser` in `UserService` ?

Comment: `export class AuthService {

    private currentUser$ = new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as User);
    
    private token = null;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {}

    getCurrentUser() {
        this.currentUser$;
    }
   
     setCurrentUser(user:User){
       this.currentUser$.next(user); 
    }}`

Comment: this looks fine. Where are you calling `UserService.setCurrentUser()` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not quite understand you, do you mean a model?

Comment: You are retrieving the current user thats fine but we need to set the current user right ?

Comment: You should set the current user in `AuthService` after login. like `userService.setCurrentUser(user)`

Comment: Like this?  `user: User;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
    this.auth.setCurrentUser(this.user)
  }`

Comment: yeah, just move `this.auth.setCurrentUser(this.user) ` to place where you get the user from server. I guess it should be in login function.

Comment: it doesn’t work anyway, do you have any example nodejs + angular 6?

Comment: You can refer this which maintains the user in localstorage https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-registration-login-example-pfnmzr?file=app%2F_services%2Fauthentication.service.ts